# Z-Wave Device ID changes in Domoticz when battery is changed

Tags: zwave, domoticz, batteries

When my Z-Wave door sensor's battery ran out, I changed it and checked if it still appeared in my [Domoticz](https://domoticz.com/) interface. The problem is that my device changed its ID and I had to redo all the trigger configuration (call program when opened).

[I searched online](http://easydomoticz.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1027) and found that Domoticz has a "replace" feature when clicking on Edit of a device in the measure/temperature view, **but only for measure sensors (temperature, light,...)** which allows users to keep history of the data.

[image: Editing device]

[image: Replace device]

Do Domoticz users have this problem too?

Is it the same on other hubs (Jeedom, Vera,...)?

Comment: Device ID or node ID? The node ID should only change on a learn mode even which replacing the batteries could trigger if it sends out a node info on boot, but then it would have to be removed and then readded to the network to get a different ID as if it was removed it would not be in the network at all.

Comment: It's a Domoticz ID : when I remove/add a device using Domoticz, it creates as many sub-devices per device capacity (class commands if you prefer) and each line of sub-device has an ID linked to the main device ID. I'll post some screenshots later for a better understanding.

Comment: @Goufalite, I am curious to know if the Device ID would would change every time you remove the battery?

Comment: @sob It's not the Device ID, it's the ID in Domoticz : it thinks it is a new device so it increments its counter in the devices database. It should match the Device ID, which puzzles me !